# pointers inside and outside parens

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
char errorString[20];
//See if it appears to be a 4-char-code
*(UInt32 *) (errorString + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(error);
if (isprint(errorString[1]) && isprint(errorString[2]) && isprint(errorString[3]) && isprint(errorString[4]))
{
    errorString[0] = errorString[5] = '\'';
    errorString[6] = '\0';
}
```

This section of a function takes a string (`error`) and checks to see if it holds a 4-char-code.

What is going on in: `*(UInt32 *) (errorString + 1)`

Why is there a pointer both inside and outside the parens, and how is a value being assigned to `errorString + 1`?

Comment: Allowing the array to decay to pointer, then reinterpret casting as a different pointer type and dereferencing. "Type punning" Although I don't fullly follow the assignment to `CFSwapInt32HostToBig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`errorString` can be treated as a pointer, so, one can do math on it, for example, add integers. `errorString + 1` is a pointer as well. It's a pointer to the location right next to the one `errorString` points to.

`(UInt32 *)something` casts `something` to a pointer of the specified type, so `(UInt32 *)(errorString + 1)` is now a pointer to data of type `UInt32`.

`*` is a dereference operator, so applying it to a pointer gets you whatever the pointer was pointing to (e.g. if `pointer` was pointing to an integer, `*pointer` will be an integer).

All in all, this construct will attempt to extract data of type `UInt32` from a specified location.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression

```
*(UInt32 *) (errorString + 1)
```

The first `*` is a dereference and then second `*` denotes a pointer.  If we read it from right to left we have

```
(errorString + 1) // get a pointer to errorString + 1 of the type char*
(UInt32 *) // cast that pointer to a UInt32 *
* // dereference that pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk inside the brackets is part of pointer casting
The asterisk outside the brackets if for deference

so `(UInt32 *) (errorString + 1)` makes errorString+1 and UInt32 pointer
and `*(UInt32 *) (errorString + 1)` derefernces it and brings you the content as a UInt32.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the beginning.

The *expression* `errorString` has type `char [20]`; except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, its type will be converted ("decay") from `char [20]` to `char *`, and its value will be the address of the first element of the array (`&errorString[0]`).

The expression `errorString + 1` yields the address of the 2nd element of the array (equivalent to `&errorString[1]`), and its type is `char *`.

`(UInt32 *) (errorString + 1)` is a *cast expression*, and it tells the compiler to treat the result of `errorString + 1` as a pointer to `UInt32` instead of a pointer to `char`.

`*(UInt32 *) (errorString + 1)` *dereferences* the result of `(UInt32 *) (errorString + 1)`, so that the result of `CFSwapInt32HostToBig()` is assigned to the *32-bit object* starting at address `errorString + 1`.

Crappy visual aid:

```
             +---+
errorString: |   | errorString[0]
             +---+                 
             |   | errorString[1]  <-------------+
             +---+                               |
             |   | errorString[2]                |
             +---+                               +-- Assign result of CFSwapInt32HostToBig()
             |   | errorString[3]                |   to these four bytes
             +---+                               |
             |   | errorString[4]  <-------------+
             +---+                 
             |   | errorString[5]
             +---+
              ...
             +---+
             |   | errorString[19]
             +---+
```